# jQuery load giving Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a local HTML page into a div using `jQuery.load` and am getting the following error:

`Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError`

My code is below:

```
var url_string = "x=bob&y=jan&dbconnection="+encodeURIComponent(DBCONNECTION_STRING);
$('#SOMEDIV').load("page.asp?"+url_string);
```

I did a console.log on the url_string and there are no extra spaces because the encodeURIComponent would have caught it.

Comment: i hope you are  not passing your connection string in the url, your database will get hacked in a matter of seconds. Also `encodeURIComponent` is a function, remove it from the quotes

Comment: This is something local for right now.  It will never ever ever ever ever ever ever touch the outside world.

Comment: Which line is giving you this error?  What is being returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: The error says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL and the line it is pointing to is jquery-1.10.2.min.js line 4

Comment: If that is the case, it has to do with the JQuery script...not your script

Comment: Have you tried to just load the page with a string written manually (outside of the variable and encode)?

Comment: The code came straight from jQuery website.  I am using this load else where in my code and passing URL variables and it works fine.

Comment: I just tried without the url string and it loaded, besides the errors on the other page looking for those variables.

Comment: is `DBCONNECTION_STRING` a variable?

Comment: Yes, DBCONNECTION_STRING is a variable